# Powershell Script With Error Log

Tags: powershell, error, library, download, log

With The help of this forum I am able to Write The following Script Using powershell which downloads bulk data from SharePoint with Metadata in CSV file and also Error log as txt file. but the problem I am facing here is, it only Copies last error.i want copy of all errors in Txt file.

I tried using

Set-Content "c:\" $error

still not able to solve it.

```
if((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell") -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

try
{
$destination = "C:\\Test\\"
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://xyz:4444/"
$list = $web.GetList("http://xyz:4444/Shared Documents/")


function ProcessFolder {
    param($folderUrl)
    $folder = $web.GetFolder($folderUrl)
    foreach ($file in $folder.Files) {
        #Ensure destination directory
        $destinationfolder = $destination + "/" + $folder.Url 
        if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationfolder))
        {
            $dest = New-Item $destinationfolder -type directory 
        }
        #Download file
        $binary = $file.OpenBinary()
        d
        e
        $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "/" + $file.Name), Create
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
        $writer.write($binary)
        $writer.Close()
          }
}
$exportlist = @()
$list.Items | foreach {
$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
"Title" = $_["Title"]
"Name" = $_["Name"]
"Modified Date" = $_["Modified"]
"Modified By" =$_["Modified By"]
"Size"= $_["File Size"]
"Path" = $web.Url + "/" + $_.File.Url

}
$exportlist += $obj
$exportlist | Export-Csv -path 'C:\Test\MyList.csv' -noType
}


#Download root files
ProcessFolder($list.RootFolder.Url)
#Download files in folders
foreach ($folder in $list.Folders) {
    ProcessFolder($folder.Url)
}
}
catch
{
#Write "Error: copy-item: $_" >>c:\logfile.txt

$("$file.name: " + $_.Exception.Message) | out-file c:\file.log -Append
#set-content "c:\log2.txt"  $error


}
finally
{
#Download root files
ProcessFolder($list.RootFolder.Url)
#Download files in folders
foreach ($folder in $list.Folders) {
    ProcessFolder($folder.Url)
}

}
#DownloadMetadata ($list.RootFolder.Url)
```

Comment: In your code sample you use Out-File -Append, does that not output all errors instead of just the last ?

Comment: no it doesn't output all.

Comment: For easier testing, maybe you can just throw some errors intentionally, so you know what errors to expect in the output.

Comment: i already tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I corrected My Try catch Block and its seems To be Working Fine

```
if((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell") -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}


$destination = "C:\\Test\\"
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://xyz:4444/"
$list = $web.GetList("http://xyx:4444/Shared Documents/")


function ProcessFolder {
    param($folderUrl)
    $folder = $web.GetFolder($folderUrl)
    foreach ($file in $folder.Files) {
        #Ensure destination directory
        $destinationfolder = $destination + "/" + $folder.Url 
        if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationfolder))
        {
            $dest = New-Item $destinationfolder -type directory 
        }
        #Download file
        try
        {

        $binary = $file.OpenBinary()
        $stream = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($destinationfolder + "/" + $file.Name), Create
        $writer = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($stream)
        $writer.write($binary)
        $writer.Close()
         }
        catch
        {
        #Add-content "c:\log3.txt"  $error
        Write "Error: $file.name: $_" >>c:\logfile.txt
        continue;
        }

        }
}

$exportlist = @()
$list.Items | foreach {
$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
"Title" = $_["Title"]
"Name" = $_["Name"]
"Modified Date" = $_["Modified"]
"Modified By" =$_["Modified By"]
"Size"= $_["File Size"]
"Path" = $web.Url + "/" + $_.File.Url

}
$exportlist += $obj
$exportlist | Export-Csv -path 'C:\Test\MyList.csv' -noType
}


#Download root files
ProcessFolder($list.RootFolder.Url)
#Download files in folders
foreach ($folder in $list.Folders) {
    ProcessFolder($folder.Url)

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You only see the last error because Set-Content overwrites the existing content, use Add-Content instead.

If you want to have a more encompassing approach, like Robert suggested, there's a more PowerShell'y (?) way of doing this with [Start/Stop-Transcript](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849687.aspx) which takes all console output between the Start & Stop cmdlet calls and outputs it to a file.

Comment: Yupp, that is the better approach. My version is more of a simple hack to get there fast ;)

Comment: Haha! Fast is not always better, this time ;)!

Comment: I Tried Using Start-Transcript -path c:\logging.txt -append just above try and used stop transcript right at the bottom.but it doesn't output any file.

Comment: Can you tell us what error you get when you type the command in a powershell prompt ? You need to have access to the file location (try C:\temp to be sure). Also, you cannot start another transcript before the first was stopped. I'm not sure but when you use -Append, it may be that the file needs to exist first.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Write-Output "Logging text"` in your catches and then when you run the script you can run it as

```
MyFancyScriptName.ps1 > C:\file.log
```

Comment: where I should run MyFancyScriptName.ps1 > C:\file.log ? I am running whole script in powershell directly

Comment: Exactly where you run your script today (in PowerShell i presume) ;)